# Cannot run python Flask app cPanel using PhusionPassenger

Tags: python, flask, cpanel, passenger

I am unable to run my flask app in cpanel

My `passenger_wsgi.py` is

```py
import os
import sys

from app import app

application = app


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

and my `app.py` is

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="static") # "index.html" is in static folder

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__': # Even tried removing this two lines but no change
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Python version used 3.11.4

Flask version used 3.0.0

It also works locally.

In the error section I am getting

`[ E 2023-11-04 03:08:30.0399 3259818/T47 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/tyj6prmi0i7p/repositories/axel: The application process exited prematurely.`

I even ensured all the folder permissions are 0755 and file permissions are 0644.

This is shown when I open the website.

[image]

Comment: Templates don't go in `static`. They go in... `templates`

Comment: I have specifically set the template dir to static in `app.py`. I even tried putting it in a new templates folder to check if that was the issue, but it was not so I reverted it back.